# Drawing Radius (Circle) on MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I have seen this question posed before and all responses appear largely similar. However, I am simply unable to get any of them to work for my project.

I have an action, updateMap, that is triggered by a button. It shows current location on map (MapKit), and shows some other info relative to their location (geocoding). All of that works fine. What I need to do though is show a radius around their location on the map. Here is what I'm trying that isn't working:

(in updateMap)

```
//display radius
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = {current.coordinate.latitude, current.coordinate.longitude};
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:center radius:1000];
[self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

("current" is a CLLocation var that has the user's current location)

Then, after the action in the implementation file I have this:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    [circleView setFillColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [circleView setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [circleView setAlpha:0.5f];
    return circleView;
}
```

It builds fine, but no circle is ever shown on the map.

Other solutions on this site involved putting the first code shown in the viewDidLoad method, but since the location hasn't been calculated yet (only determined within above-mentioned action) that isn't an option for me.

I appreciate your time and any help you can provide. I'm by no means on the level of many on here so please excuse me if this has an obvious answer. I'm not wanting to be spoon fed, I'm wanting to learn! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Code looks fine - the only thing I could think of: how are the dimensions of your mapView? Are 1000m simply too small to be displayed? And is the coordinate on the map?

Comment: Have you verified that current has the numbers you are expecting?

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I added "mapView.delegate = self;" to the viewDidLoad method and that did the trick. I had declared "MKMapViewDelegate" at the @interface of the UIViewController in the .h file, but obviously that wasn't enough.